# Who is "your brother" in Deuteronomy 22:1-3?

Tags: word-study, deuteronomy, definition, word-choice, biblical-application

Deuteronomy 22:1-3 reads (NKJV, emphasis mine):

> "You shall not see **your brother**’s ox or his sheep going astray, and hide yourself from them; you shall certainly bring them back to **your brother**. And if **your brother** is not near you, or if you do not know him, then you shall bring it to your own house, and it shall remain with you until **your brother** seeks it; then you shall restore it to him. You shall do the same with his donkey, and so shall you do with his garment; with any lost thing of **your brother**’s, which he has lost and you have found, you shall do likewise; you must not hide yourself."

Who is "your brother" in this passage? To whom were the children of Israel expected to return lost items such as animals and cloaks?

1. Fellow Jews (but not necessarily Gentiles)
2. Jews and proselytes to Judaism (but not necessarily heathens)
3. Anyone living in Israel (but not necessarily those of other nations)
4. Everyone
5. None of the above

In the event that the "technical" answer differs from the "heart" answer (which perhaps could carry weight given the parable of the Good Samaritan [Luke 10:25-37]), feel free to include that as well.

Answer (score 4):

The term "brother" (אָח ach) in the Torah can either mean a man born of the same mother, or, a fellow Israelite as per Deut 1:16, 3:18, 23:20, 24:7, 25:3, 14, 17:15, 25, 15:7, 11, 19:18, Lev 25:35, 39, 47, Judges 20:23, etc.

Thus, I would understand that Deut 22 applies primarily to "brothers" as fellow-Israelites.

However, and this is a significant "but", with very few exceptions, the laws of the Torah were to apply to non-Israelites/aliens as much as to Israelites - see appendix below.

The exceptions appear to be those laws surrounding slavery and money lending.  Apart from these, the laws of love, compassion, and welfare especially, applied to aliens and resident Israelites alike.

Jesus emphasized this same point by quoting Isa 56:7 -

> Mark 11:17 - And he was teaching them and saying to them, “Is it not
> written, ‘My house shall be called **a house of prayer for all the
> nations**’? ...

**APPENDIX - Rule of Law on the Torah - Foreigners Vs Israelites.**

- Ex 12:49 - The **same law shall apply to both the native and the foreigner** who resides among you.”
- Ex 22:21 - **You must not exploit or oppress a foreign resident**, for you yourselves were foreigners in the land of Egypt.
- Ex 23:12 - For six days you are to do your work, but on the seventh day you must cease, so that your ox and your donkey may rest and the son of your maidservant may be refreshed, **as well as the foreign resident**.
- Lev 16:29 - This is to be a permanent statute for you: On the tenth day of the seventh month, you shall humble yourselves and not do any work—**whether the native or the foreigner** who resides among you—
- Lev 19:34 - You must **treat the foreigner living among you as native-born** and love him as yourself, for you were foreigners in the land of Egypt. I am the LORD your God.
- Num 9:14 - If a foreigner dwelling among you wants to observe the Passover to the LORD, he is to do so according to the Passover statute and its ordinances. You are to apply **the same statute to both the foreigner** and the native of the land.’ ”
- Num 15:15 - The assembly is to have the same statute both for you and for the foreign resident; it is a permanent statute for the generations to come. You and the **foreigner shall be the same** before the LORD.
- Num 15:16 - The **same law and the same ordinance will apply both to you and to the foreigner** residing with you.”
- Num 15:29 - You shall have the **same law** for the one who acts in error, **whether he is a native-born Israelite or a foreigner** residing among you.
- Num 24:22 - You are to have the **same standard of law for the foreign resident and the native**; for I am the LORD your God.’ ”
- Deut 10:19 - So you also must **love the foreigner**, since you yourselves were foreigners in the land of Egypt.
- Num 19:10 - The man who has gathered up the ashes of the heifer must also wash his clothes, and he will be ceremonially unclean until evening. This is a permanent **statute for the Israelites and for the foreigner** residing among them.